# How to describe error from Alamofire using switch case in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to give info to the user about the error that occurred while sending a request to the server. I use Alamofire.

The code is like below:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: methodUsed, parameters: parameters).responseData { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error) : 
        // I want to the describe the error in here
    case .success(let value) :
        let json = JSON(value)
        completion(.success(json))
    }
}
```

I have tried but I can't switch the error. I want something similar to this to be placed in the code above:

```
switch error {
    case .NoSignal : // give alert to the user about the signal
    case .ServerError : // give alert to the user about server error
}
```

For some case I want to inform the user to take some action on the alert but I don't know what the available cases are and I don't know the syntax that has to be used.

Comment: You can use error.localizeddescription to print or show alert to user what alamofire is returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Jayesh Thanki says you can identify the server error using status code and for internet connectivity you can use **NetworkReachabilityManager** of Alamofire. Write following code in viewDidLoad():

```
var networkManager: NetworkReachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()!
networkManager.startListening()
networkManager.listener = { (status) -> Void in
if status == NetworkReachabilityManager.NetworkReachabilityStatus.notReachable {
   print("No internet available")
}else{
   print("Internet available")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify error using status code. `response.response.statusCode`.
There is lots of HTTP status code and using them you can inform end user with alert.

Here is [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) link for list of status code.

For example is status code is 200 `OK` then its successful HTTP request
and status code is 500 `Internal Server Error` then its server related error.

You can also provide error description using `response.result.error.localizedDescription` if error is available.